# How to make UITableViewCell twice the size on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I am using a simple prototype cell in a UITableViewController, simply using the built in imageView and description.

This looks good on iPhone but on the larger iPad I would like the cell to be twice as big so to say, I want the image to be twice the size, the text to be larger, I just cannot seem to figure it out

I have tried the following

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 120;
}
```

No matter I change the 120 to be 1500 there is no change in cell size at all so what do I need to do to allow everything to scale up on iPad?

Comment: Because you have a dynamic cell height so it doesn't matter if you can 120 to be 1500. To change height of cell, you should change text size, imageSize.. in your cell. Can your show us you custom cell and xib if you use ?

Comment: I am not using a custom cell, I am using the standard prototype cell that comes with the UITableViewController so I have not modified anything simply adding cell.imageView.image = foo and cell.textLabel.text = @"bar"

Comment: Use a number instead of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. You don't need `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` method here. Check and change height of cell inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Ok but will that stretch and change my text size and image size ?

Comment: It will change image size but don't change text size. You need to check and change text size in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: have you tried using Aspect Ratio constraint?

Comment: No how does that work ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // set whatever height you want for your layout. 
  return 1200.0f;
}
```

you can comment the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

Try this after commenting **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


 if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad))
 {
     return 240;

  }
  else
  {
      return 120;
 }
```

}